# Apache not starting with mod_session_crypto

Tags: apache-2.4

When I enable mod_session_crypto by uncommenting it from the config, apache server fails to start. I found the following error from the journalctl:

```
Jan 09 12:27:39 dbserver1 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 09 12:27:39 dbserver1 kill[18321]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jan 09 12:27:39 dbserver1 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 09 12:27:39 dbserver1 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jan 09 12:27:39 dbserver1 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 09 12:27:39 dbserver1 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Jan 09 12:27:39 dbserver1 polkitd[1053]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:18219:214619083 (system bus name :1
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong from it.

When I disable the `mod_session_crypto`, `mod_auth_form` is not creating cookie - seems like it's refusing to create a cookie with unencrypted username and password when I use `AuthProvider ldap`. Worked fine with `AuthProvider basic`.

This setting worked just fine on my other computer I use for development.

Dev PC (works):
CentOS 7.4.1708
Apache 2.4.6-67.el7
mod_session 2.4.6-67.el7

Production PC (doesn't start):
CentOS 7.5.1808
Apache 2.4.6-80.el7
mod_session 2.4.6-80.el7

As you can see there's a slight difference in OS version. Beside that, I cannot find anything different.

Comment: The first place you should be looking is in the apache error_log.

Comment: You are right. I found the following in it: `The crypto library 'openssl' could not be loaded`. I didn't think it would write into the log file without successfully starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the symcbean's tip, I found the following error message logged in the apache error log:

```
[Wed Jan 09 12:49:53.410386 2019] [session_crypto:error] [pid 30523] (20019)DSO load failed: AH01845: The crypto library 'openssl' could not be loaded: /usr/lib64/apr-util-1/apr_crypto_openssl-1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (apr_crypto_openssl-1.so: 0)
```

According to the bug report [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1633260), all that's needed is to install `apr-util-openssl` package, e.g. with `yum install apr-util-openssl`.